# How to throw exceptions when called from library?

Tags: c#, exception

I am defining a convention for the AutoMapping in Fluent NHibernate. From within this convention, I throw an exception:

```
public void Apply(IManyToManyCollectionInstance instance){
  ...
  if(<error>)
    throw new MappingException("Invalid Mapping");

  <doSomeStuff>
}
```

In another class, I initialize the configuration, resulting in the code above being executed:

```
public void init(){
  try{
    SessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory(); // Apply(...) will be called here
  }
  catch (MappingException ex)
  {
    <catchError>
  }
```

When `<error>` is true, `<doSomeStuff>` is highlighted by VisualStudio and I am warned that "MappingException was unhandled by user code".

Why is the exception not thrown until `<catchError>`?

The Fluent NHibernate library is added by the NuGet package manager. If this is the reason that the exception is not forwarded, how can I send the MappingException to `<catchError>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behavior most likely is that you have checked the following option:
Debug -> Exceptions -> Column "Thrown" for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".

If you hit F5 or otherwise continue debugging, the code will eventually reach `<catchError>`.